# Reactive non-blocking I/O call web socket will stack overflow?

Tags: netty, spring-webflux, reactive

In a trandational multi-threaded model like tomcat servlet, we will call web socket in synchronize so we can controll the rate even if it is slowly.

```
thread: {
        Obj request;
        // There are at most several socket for threads num
        Obj response = syncClient.blockingWebRequest(request);
        // ...
        logicHandle();
        // ...
        return response;
    }
```

But in reactive non-blocking I/O, we will call socket in asychronize, so if request too more, will call lots of web socket currently. Can OS socket stack hold it? And how about buffer?

```
eventLoop: {
        Mono request;
        // Non-blocking IO continuously receives and establishes socket
        Mono response = asyncClient.nonBlockingWebRequest(request);
        response.onSubscribe(()->{
            // ...
            logicHandle();
            // ...
        });
        return response;
    }
```

For example, establish millions of socket connections at the same time.

- socket take 10s.
- CPU computes 1ms.

Will 10,000 socket connections be made before the first socket returns?

```
eventLoop: {
        // eventLoop handles one in 1ms
        Mono request;
        // Non-blocking IO continuously receives and establishes socket
        Mono response = asyncClient.nonBlockingWebRequest(request);
        // This will callback after 10s
        response.onSubscribe(()->{
            // ...
            logicHandle();
            // ...
        });
        // eventLoop continue
        return response;
    }
```

Thanks very much for answering my question!

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I added pseudocode to my description

Answer (score 0):

No doubt, if the rate is very high, eventually the buffer will be full.

The overflow of the buffer will be fed back from the receiving side to the sending side via TCP.

Back pressure is one solution.

To be clear, the connection will be reused if a protocol like RSocket.